# Closing keyboard leaves white portion in Fragment which are in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

I am using fragments in my application which are in `Viewpager`. There is `Scrollview` in all of the fragments containing many views. When user click on `Edittext`, keyboard opens but when user click done button on keyboard then keyboard get hidden leaving black screen. I tried a lot my self but no luck. Please guide me..

Have tried almost all the possibilities of `configChanges` and `windowSoftInputMode` in manifest file of my activity like,

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

And if i load that `fragment` without `viewpager` than its working perfectly fine. The issue is with `viewpager` and fragments with scroll.[With keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwAbd.png) [image: Keyboard Closed.]

Comment: which adapter you have used FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePageAdapter?

Comment: Could you give me a screenshot with issue?

Comment: @Rajesh - FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: if you need scroll then why you not put in activity's layout(global scrollview) rather than fragment layout?

Comment: can you try removing scrollbar from fragment then use only in mainview

Comment: @Rajesh ok let me try..

Comment: @Rajesh  I have tried doing same thing. Kept scrollview in activity and removed from fragment layout but still no change.

Comment: ok wait few minutes

Comment: i have implemeted same using  http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/ and its working